# How do i send a 2d array with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am currently trying to send a 2d array that i receive from a database (sql, phpmyadmin) with ajax.

My ajax function looks like this: (it is generated in php)

```
$.ajax({
        type: \"POST\",
        url: \"resultQuizGet.php\",
        data: \"getAnswer=\"+question+\"\", //question is just a int variable
        success: function(msg) {
           alert(\"Data Saved: \" + msg);
           }
 });
```

my resultQuizGet.php file then look like

```
 $sql = "SELECT `quiz`.question,`quiz`.rightAnswer 
 FROM `quiz` 
 WHERE `quiz`.quizID=:qID";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":qID", $_POST['quiz']);
$stmt->execute();
$resultsQuiz = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo ...
```

What do i have to do now to receive a 2d array instead of just a normal string.

What i would like to the msg variable to be is a 2d array that is equal to $resultsQuiz

Comment: In the php, if it's an array, use `json_encode` to pass it as a structured array to your ajax call.  Then, in your jQuery, use `$.parseJSON()` to convert it from the json string to an array.

Comment: I was looking at it but i dident make it work. I found out something about json_encode() and JSON.stringify() but couldent make it work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your php as follows, to output the data as a json formatted string:

```
$sql = "SELECT `quiz`.question,`quiz`.rightAnswer 
 FROM `quiz` 
 WHERE `quiz`.quizID=:qID";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":qID", $_POST['quiz']);
$stmt->execute();
$resultsQuiz = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($resultsQuiz);
```

Then, modify your jQuery as follow to parse that structured string back into an array / object:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resultQuizGet.php",
        data: "getAnswer="+question, //question is just a int variable
        success: function(msg) {
           // Note: if it's not json, this can cause a problem
           var data = $.parseJSON(msg);
           // output to your console so you can see the structure
           console.log(data);
           // Utilize the data somehow
           $.each(data, function(key, arr) {
               // Arr should contain an object / array representing the rows from your php results
               console.log(arr);
               // If your row has a field titled `question`, you can access it one of two ways:
               alert(arr.question); // Object notation
               alert(arr['question']); // Array notation
           });
        }
 });
```

Comment: i have tried this, but i couldent continiue with how to get the 2d array from here

Comment: @RobinAndersson - see my revisions.  Funny you asked, because I was editing to show this before your comment came in...